# PowerShell. Remove Forbidden Characters

Tags: powershell

What are the good ways of replacing uppercase letters to lower case letters while leaving only numbers and dashes from the strings with PowerShell?

We are automating deployment of Azure resources based on some strings. A lot of Azure Resources can only have in their names combinations of lowercase letters, numbers and dashes.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you [trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)? Depending on your use case, maybe a regex will work, maybe it won't. For example, working with non-latin character sets is going to be a more tricky than one [might expect](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: We are automating deployment of Azure resources that can't have anything in their name but lowercase letters, numbers and dashes.

Comment: Please add this to your question. Also provide examples and code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftcontainerinstance), valid names are:
*Lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Can't start or end with hyphen. Consecutive hyphens aren't allowed. Length 1-63 characters*

To make sure a proposed name obides by these rules, one way would be to use a series of `-replace` actions, followed by trimming any possible hyphens at the beginning or start of the string, convert to lowercase and finally truncate the remaining string to the 63 character limit.

Something like this:

```
$proposedName = '_Container___Name-123-'
$containerName = (($proposedName -replace '[^-a-z0-9]', '-' -replace                   # any character not hyphen, letter or digit --> '-'
                                          '-{2,}', '-').Trim("-").ToLower() -replace   # remove leading and trailing hyphens and convert to lowercase
                                          '(.{63}).*', '$1').TrimEnd("-")              # truncate to 63 characters and trim any trailing hyphens

$containerName # --> container-name-123
```